# NetLogo create-movie: where to find and how to add VID extension?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create a movie from my NetLogo model. I followed the `Movies example` here: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#movies

I have added the parts of code into my model, and created the button "make-movie" in my interface.

```
extensions [vid]
```

; ....

```
to make-movie

  setup
 vid:start-recorder
 vid:record-interface ;; show the initial state
 repeat 2
 [ go
   vid:record-view ]
 vid:save-recording "out.mp4"

end
```

When I try to run it, I have an error: `Can't find extension: vid` and NetLogo directs me on the github website: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions to download one. However, there is no VID extension. I think the closest is the `Gst-Video` so I downloaded it, unzipped the files and copied the files to this location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\NetLogo 5.2.1\app\extensions`, as I run on 64-bit Windows with 32-bit NetLogo.

NetLogo still can't find this extension.

Please, where can I find the VID extension? And how can I correctly add this extension in the extension library? Is is sufficient just copy, unzip and paste the downloaded file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using Netlogo 5.2.1- `Vid` was [added in 6.0](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#v60). You should upgrade to the latest version if you want to use `Vid`. If you don't want to upgrade, you should still be able to use the `movie` primitives in version 5.2.