# NetLogo create-movie: speed is too fast when played from file

Tags: netlogo

So I wrote a NetLogo (v6.3) program. Now I would like to record a video to be embedded within a powerpoint presentation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908022/netlogo-create-movie-where-to-find-and-how-to-add-vid-extension) I found the following code that does this:

```
extensions [vid]

to make-movie

  setup
 vid:start-recorder
 vid:record-interface ;; show the initial state
 repeat 2
 [ go
   vid:record-view ]
 vid:save-recording "out.mp4"

end
```

But upon playing the created .mp4 file using QuickTime, i notice that the speed is much faster than shown in NetLogo. It's too fast (or faster than I'd like) to be shown in a powerpoint when presenting to a group of people. Has anyone experienced this too, and what could be a workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#movies it says:

> A movie will play back at 25 frames per second. To make the movie playback faster or slower, consider using a video postprocessing tool.

Comment: Ok cheers. I found a useful website that allows me to do this easily and quickly, for anyone interested: https://www.veed.io/tools/video-frame-rate-converter